# WPF how to open Excel File and Read Data From the file Cell by Cell

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

Im trying to Introduced and Read From Excel File i have a loop and each time it goes inside the Loop i like to Read New Cell Lets Say "Cell+1" There are few Method i saw online for Assign and Read Data From Excel But I can't make them work In WPF/c# any help would be great to how to Introduced the Excel file which is Store in c:/ExcelFolder/Excel.xls and Read Data From it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office).